# In sql how to select rows with no NULL value and get the output in single row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-server-2008, relational-database

### REF         Priority        owner           server

1234        LOW             NULL            NULL

4567        NULL            NULL            WINDOWS

8907        NULL            root            NULL

Can I get the above output in single row excluding null values:

### REF         Priority        owner           server

1234        LOW             root            windows

Comment: Is this for Oracle or SQL Server? or are you looking for a general solution?

Answer (score 1):

try min and max functions.

```
select min(ref), max(prio), max(owner), max(server)
from yourTable;
```